# Sort an array of object into a cleaner array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array of object to a cleaner array of objects with specific attributes.

I'm fetching an api that's returning me a huge array of object

For the moment i didn't figure out how to get the array like this:

```
    results= [
{'author' : Mister1,'url':'http://url1.com','score':400},
{'author' : Mister2,'url':'http://url2.com','score':350},
{'author' : Mister3,'url':'http://url3.com','score':500},
{'author' : Mister4,'url':'http://url1.com','score':456},
]
```

this is my code :

```
function fetchSearchTopStories(term) {
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${term}/top.json`, { responseType: 'json' }).then(response => {
const tab = (response.data.data.children)
      for (let i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
       results.url= tab[i].data.url
       results.author = tab[i].data.author
       results.score= tab[i].data.score
        console.log(results)
      }
 return results
    })
}
```

Unfortunately this is not inserting in the array but creating every time a new array with only one field instead of many.

Thank you very much

Comment: In function where result is defined ?

Comment: Please show a reduced example of input and desired output.

Comment: exactly, as @connexo says, you need to show the input and the output so we can see the error or the problem in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create an array to store your `result`. To make it easier than a for loop, you could use `.map()` to create a new array from the old one by transforming each object.

```js
function fetchSearchTopStories(term) {
  axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${term}/top.json`, {
    responseType: 'json'
  }).then(response => {
    const tab = (response.data.data.children)
    const results = tab.map(t => {
      return {
        url: t.data.url,
        author: t.data.author,
        score: t.data.score
      }
    });
    console.log(results)
  });
}

fetchSearchTopStories('javascript');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your code more concise with **ES6** and object destructuring:

```js
function fetchSearchTopStories(term) {
  axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${term}/top.json`, {
    responseType: 'json'
  }).then(r => console.log(r.data.data.children.map(({data}) => {
    let {url, author, score} = data
    return {url, author, score}
  })))
}

fetchSearchTopStories('javascript');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```